# How do I implement an IUndoableOperation in my RCP application using my own IUndoContext

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've implemented my operation class and it extends org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.AbstractOperation so it has implementations of the methods execute(), redo(), and undo().  At first, I could only get the execute() method to be called, but I could never see an undo or redo command become available on my Eclipse undo redo buttons.

Then I installed an example plugin into my RCP application (org.eclipse.ui.examples.undo), and magic started happening.

Using the view "Undo History View" that came with the example plugin, I could see my custom undo and redo items being added to the stack of things to undo and redo.  Plus, when the "Undo History View" is active, my custom undo redo actions are showing up in the Eclipse undo redo buttons.  So, it's working, but there's a problem.

When I select my view part the items disappear from the Eclipse undo redo buttons.  My assumption is that I'm not using the IUndoContext correctly.

Here's what I have as far as execution of the operation.  My InventoryLabelOperation class extends org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.AbstractOperation.  And the activePart field is an instance of my View Part that I want to have play correctly with the IUndoContext, but it's not.

```
InventoryLabelOperation operation = new InventoryLabelOperation(message + name);
IOperationHistory operationHistory = OperationHistoryFactory.getOperationHistory();
IWorkbench workbench = activePart.getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getWorkbench();
IUndoContext undoContext = workbench.getOperationSupport().getUndoContext();
operation.addContext(undoContext);
operationHistory.execute(operation, new NullProgressMonitor(), null);
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was doing everything correctly on the operation creation side of things.  The issue turned out to be the fact that the view part I'm developing extends CommonNavigator class that extends ViewPart (because my view is taking advantage of the Common Navigator Framework).   I didn't realize that the CommonNavigator was setting its own context and therefore causing my undo operation that was using the workbench context to be correctly not shown.

Once I had my operation use the context returned from this call...

```
undoContext = 
    (IUndoContext) ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getAdapter(IUndoContext.class);
```

Things started showing up in the UI as expected.